# Kotlin: Elegant way to sum elements across the rows in matrix?

Tags: matrix, kotlin, functional-programming, mapping, column-sum

Given an [`ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) (rows) of [`ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) (elements in a row), is there a better way to obtain a list of sums like  (`row[0][0] + row[1][0] + .... row[n][0]`) except writing a "`for`" loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) and [`sumBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) to achieve this.

Following are 3 methods: (1) to calculate the overall matrix sum, (2) to calculate the sum for a given row, and (3) to calculate the sum for a given column:

```
val arr = arrayListOf(
        arrayListOf(1, 2, 3),
        arrayListOf(4, 5, 6),
        arrayListOf(7, 8, 9)
)

fun matrixSum() = arr.sumBy { it.sum() }
fun rowSum(row: Int) = arr[row].sum()
fun colSum(col: Int) = arr.sumBy {row -> row[col] }
// shorter alternative: fun colSum(col: Int) = arr.sumBy { it[col] }
```

According to your question, you would like to call `colSum(0)`. This will extract `row[0]` (each row's value for index `0`) and sum these values.

EDIT:

Regarding your question in the comment section, following two methods: (1) To calculate all row sums, returned as a list; and (2) To calculate all col sums, returned as a list.

```
fun rowSums() = arr.map { it.sum() }
fun colSums() = arr[0].indices.map { col -> colSum(col) }
// shorter alternative:
// fun colSums() = arr[0].indices.map(::colSum)
// another version that does not call colSum:
// fun colSums() = arr[0].indices.map { col -> arr.sumBy { row -> row[col] } }
```

To explain `colSums` (which assumes that all rows have the same number of columns): First, you grab your first row (`arr[0]`), then you get its [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) (i.e., its column numbers `0`, `1`, ..., up to `nCols`), and then you [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) these indices to their respective `colSum()` results. This may not be the most performant way, but it's quite readable.

Comment: Ok, so I can get colSum(0), how can I use it in a map {} to receive an array as sum of all columns ? I just tried several syntax options and cannot get it.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Better `arr[row]`, not `arr.get(row)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
val matrix = arrayListOf(
        arrayListOf(1, 2, 3),
        arrayListOf(4, 5, 6),
        arrayListOf(7, 8, 9)
)
val allSum = matrix.sumBy { it.sumBy { it } } // 45
val firstColumnSum = matrix.sumBy { it[0] } // 12
```